# How do I access the Diablo 3 auction house?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've heard that the auction house is available both via in-game menus (whether playing a game or not) and over Battle.net.

However, I can't figure out how to access it through either approach, and there's some conflicting information ([1](http://www.diablowiki.com/Auction_House)),([2](http://www.diablowiki.net/Auction_House#Interface)),([3](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/services/auction-house/info#q3)).

How can I access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone coming across this, the auction house (both gold and real money one) was removed from the game in 2014. https://us.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/9972208129

Comment: You should form this into a new answer that basically says that the auction house is no longer available and use the link as reference.  Maybe quote the link as well to make a higher quality post.  Right now - it's sort of unclear that is what you mean.

Answer (score 5):

There's a fairly simple step-by-step guide on [Blizzard's site](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/services/auction-house/how-to#choose):

1. You will need to log into the auction house through Diablo 3 by signing into Diablo 3 and **clicking Auction House from the left-hand side of the character selection screen**. In the top-right corner of the auction house, you can access the real-money auction house.
   [image: See where the mouse is? On the left-hand side?]
2. To buy, in the buy tab, find something you want to buy using the search in the auction house, click on it and place a bid.
   [image]
3. To sell, in the sell tab, select the item in your inventory and set bidding criteria.
   [image]
4. Use the Auctions tab to view the status of your auctions.

View the [Auction House FAQ](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-auction-house-general-information) for more.